# Jupyter notebook - Converted Python dataset to R Dataframe. Got stuck in converting back from R to Python Dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, jupyter

I am able to Install Anaconda and able to write Python and R code without any issues based on below help. 
https://gist.github.com/simecek/019d87c55fec3839d95bbf8489dde61d

- I extracted my data from MS-SQLServer via pypyodbc
- Converted the Python dataset to R and maniputed the data (as per my usecase)
- Now I am ready to convert my R dataframe back to Python -> Got stuck

The question is..is it possible to convert R dataframe to Python dataframe (as a new dataframe)

Here, my final preparations should be done via Python.

I search for above issue for 3 hours and no luck. Please help.

Comment: have to tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630121/pandas-how-to-convert-r-dataframe-back-to-pandas)

Comment: You're already pulling from a database: why not just use that as an intermediary to pass data between R and python?

Comment: I am pulling data from Database to Python, moving to R to do some statistics and finally I want to move the 'Summary of Statistics' to Python. Overall my question here is ...can I move my dataframe from R to Python.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer for my own question. I hope this helps to others. Thanks

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html